# Rails: as_json ignoring parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to make a "not simple" query using ActiveRecord:

```
ChatRoom.first.as_json(include: {
    chat_room_members: {
         include:{
             user: {                    
                 include: [
                     hero_page: {
                         only: [:torch_id]
                     }, 
                     card: {
                         only: [:crop_y]
                     }
                 ]
             }
         }}})
```

In the model, a `ChatRoom` has many `ChatRoomMembers`, that has an `User`, that has a `HeroPage` and a `Card`.

The problem is that ActiveRecord completely ignores the argument `card`. More specifically, ignores the all arguments after the first argument inside `user: include{}`:

```
{  
   "id"   =>22,
   "chat_room_members"   =>   [  
      {  
         "id"         =>7,
         "user"         =>         {  
            "id"            =>22,
            "hero_page"            =>            {  
               "torch_id"               =>"superhero23"
            },
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

But if I remove the `only` argument from either `hero_page` or `card`, ActiveRecord show everything fine. Exemple:

```
[...]
    include: [
        hero_page: {
            only: [:torch_id]
        }, 
        :card
    ]
[...]
```

Other weird fact is that I can type anything (respecting syntax) in the second argument and in causes no error. Example:

```
[...]
    include: [
        hero_page: {
            only: [:torch_id]
        }, 
        this: {
            only: [:doesnt, :cause, :error]
        }
    ]
[...]
```

Just like in the first example, shows only `hero_page` and ignore the other parameter, `this`, that doesn't even exists.

Does someone know why the second argument is ignored in those cases??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user.include` needs to be hash not an Array as you have done currently.